# Is there any truth to the claim that the original home of the Amazons was Sinope, not Themiscyra?

Tags: greek, amazons

From the [Wikipedia entry about Otrera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otrera), the founder of the Amazons:

> One day Otreta and her women rebelled and took over the entire town and eventually all the towns surrounding. Otrera would march into neighboring towns liberate the women then slaughter and enslave the men. Otrera decided to flee the country with her people and **founded the capital city Sinope**, there she trained her armies and gathered recruits, while gradually expanding her territory.

The only websites I can find that mention this seem to be copy-pasted from Wikipedia (or vice versa). I can't find any mention of this when researching Sinope itself (modern-day Sinop, Turkey), and various articles about the Amazons mention Sinope in a list of cities founded by the Amazons, but not as their original capital.

The article also references Percy Jackson for some of its other claims, so I'm doubting its veracity, but I was curious if maybe it's just drawn from some lesser-known source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Braund in *Myth and Ritual at Sinope: From Diogenes the Cynic to Sanape the Amazon* and Askold Ivantchik in *[Les légendes de fondation de Sinope du Pont](https://www.persee.fr/doc/rea_0035-2004_1997_num_99_1_4675)* (in french) give thorough overviews on the foundation myths of Sinope (which are surprisingly rich). There are indeed some references to the Amazons, for example:

> Then Sinope a polis named after one of the Amazons, dwelling nearby. Once indigenous
> Syrians inhabited it.
> <sub>Pseudo-Scymnus 986-97</sub>

and

> Andron of Teos says that one of the Amazons, fleeing to Pontos (eis Ponton), married
> the king of that region, and because she drank too much wine she was called Sanape.
> Since heavy-drinking women are called Sanapai by the Thracians, a dialect that the
> Amazons use too, the city was called Sanape, and later by corruption, Sinope. The
> heavy-drinking Amazon left this city for Lytidas, as Hecataeus relates.
> <sub>Scholiast on Apollonius Rhodius, 2. 946ff.</sub>

and

> Having taken the city of Sinope Herakles expelled the Amazons and settled
> Greeks in it...
> <sub>IG XIV, 1293, lines 93-104</sub>

It is never hinted that the city of Sinope was founded by Otrera, or that it was the capital/original home of the Amazons.
Also, both authors stress the fact that the best-established foundation myths of Sinope concern the [nymph Sinope](https://www.theoi.com/Nymphe/NympheSinope.html), and not an amazon.

So yeah, that Wikipedia passage seems dubious at best.